# COALESCE in SQL Server vs COALESCE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, coalesce

As we all know `COALESCE` is an ANSI SQL standard function. It has the same functionality across different `RDBMS` (ie) It returns the first `NOT NULL` value from list of values.

Consider the following data setup

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (customerID varchar(10), salary int);
INSERT INTO TableA (customerID, salary)
VALUES
    ('A1', 100),
    ('A2', 200),
    ('A3', 300),
    ('A4',400);

CREATE TABLE TableB (customerID varchar(10), rate int);
INSERT INTO TableB (customerID, rate)
VALUES
    ('A1', 2),
    ('A2', 3),
    ('A3', 4);
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT t1.customerID,
       COALESCE(t1.salary * t2.rate, 'NA') AS salary
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2
    ON t1.customerID = t2.customerID
```

In **SQL Server** when I ran the above code, it generates the following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 64 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'NA' to data type int.

It's because `COALESCE` function will convert the `NA` to Integer since `Integer` has higher precedence than `varchar`.

When we run the same code in **MySQL** it works. Here is the [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67849/1)

My question is, Why an **ANSI SQL** function implemented in two different ways in two different RDBMS(**SQL Server** & **MySQL**). Till now my thought was ANSI SQL function behaves in same way in all RDBMS!

Comment: It's really a good question and getting same Conversion issue while using IFNULL and ISNULL in the same way. +1

Comment: @Suraz - We can agree with their own implementations  like `ISNULL` or `IFNULL`. But `COALESCE` is an ANSI SQL function which should work in same way across all `RDBMS`

Comment: I doubt there's any real rhyme or reason to it. It is likely a case of, "it just is..." e.g. Whoever made the decision to do it that way in MySQL likely just had a "return a result, any result..." mentality when deciding to cast the input to a common type and I doubt there's any deeper reason than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, The `COALESCE` is implemented in the same way in both databases as achieving this goal:

> Returning first Non-Null parameter

But there is a policy in SQL Server that is not in MySQL, something like:

> Just same values can union as one column

Above policy is applied in many queries:
e.g.:

```
SELECT 1 AS column1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c'
```

```
SELECT 
     CASE A 
         WHEN 1 THEN 1
         WHEN 2 THEN 'c'
     END
 FROM ...
```

```
....
```

I think this is not related to implementation of `COALESCE` it's related to query policies of databases.

Answer (score 0):

One what I found the reason of difference

COALESCE return type in

MYSQL : Return the first non-NULL argument

SQL SERVER: Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence

COALESCE is built on such a way in MYSQL that it returns first not null value of any type but in SQL SERVER it always compare/check with all data type that we are using in the COALESCE to return in the highest precedence. So we have to use same data type for getting error free result.

Comment: Thats what my question is, why we have two different implementation for an ANSI SQL function